# Overflow hidden div moves content to the right

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have two dives. One inside another. The parent have `overlow: hidden;` and some additional styles:

```
.parent {
    width: 800px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 49%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and there is a child which have this style:

```
.child {
    width: 5000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

so, my problem is that the child which is very wide is moving fully to the right, like this:

[image]

why it's happening, it should stay from left to right in the parent div like this:

[image]

where is the problem? Anybody can help?

Comment: I created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Natlalie/7kq97f8z/1/) to see if I could replicate your issue. In the fiddle it looks correct to me. Could you update your question with a fiddle or likewise where your problem is present? :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have too much css attributes. You actually have 2 different position attribute on your parent.

```
 <style>
 .parent {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    overlow: hidden;
 }
 .child {
    width:600px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
 }
 </style>

 <div class="parent">text
    <div class="child">text</div>
 </div>
```

Just try to stay simple.

Answer (score 0):

You're using twice the attribute `position` with `relative` and `absolute` in div parent. Maybe that's your error. Or, maybe is this what you want: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYjwer) 
You're using `overflow` and `opacity 0`, the child is not going to anywhere.

Comment: opacity is changing by JS to the 1, positions are from two different SASS mixins, but they supersede by last defined one

Comment: Put the children with left: 0.